# Ionic 2 create a wav file from samples/blob

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, blob, wav

I am using **cordova-audio-input**, to record audio. I get a file full of samples properly, then i use [WawAudioEncoder.js](https://github.com/higuma/wav-audio-encoder-js) to create a blob from samples.

After these steps, i use **cordova-file-plugin**, to create a wav file with this blob, but when i read this file as base64 i get a string something like this:

> data:audio/x-wav;base64,UklGRjAAAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEARKwAABCxAgACABAAZGF0YQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

The end of the file is full of "A", which means there are no data, if i am right (If i create longer audio there will be more "A", instead of any data).

That's why my audio player (**cordova-media-plugi**n) and phone default audio player shows it empty to me (audio with zero length).

So can i check a blob? Is there any data, so the encoder is working properly? Or the filewriter cause problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I solved this, but my mistake is very ridiculous. I **push**ing to an array, and the encoder creating a blob from the first array element only, so when i changed it to **concatenate** it works properly.

Comment: i am trying to acheive the same where i need to capture audio from the user in wav file and then send it to the api in binary format...could you help me with it?

Comment: It was my thesis job, and unfortunately I did not use Ionic/Cordova a long time ago. However, after you recorded the data with WavAudioEncoder, try to read the file with `readAsBinaryString`? I hope it can help your needs.